# Getting duplicate ID fields when querying by id HBS and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am trying to set up a page where I can query by ID but for some reason I am getting duplicate ID fields. Can someone explain how I am getting this result.

Here is the object:

```
{
  "_id": "5c46512ccc52b9b719753450",
  "name": "forest park",
  "description": "a park in the forest"
}
```

This is the code from server.js

```
app.get("/parks/:id", (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  Park.findById(id)
    .then(parks => {
      if (!parks) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }
      res.render("parks", {
        parks: parks
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(400).send();
    });
});
```

Here is my views/parks page

```
{{#each parks}}
  {{#if _id }}<p class='parkId'>{{_id}}</p>{{/if}}
  {{#if name }}<p class='parkName'>{{name}}</p>{{/if}}
  {{#if description}}<p class='parkDescription'>{{description}}</p>{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Response from Postman

```
<p class='parkId'>5c46512ccc52b9b719753450</p>
<p class='parkId'>5c46512ccc52b9b719753450</p>
<p class='parkName'>forest park</p>
<p class='parkDescription'>a park in the forest</p>
```

Comment: I ended up creating a new file for the individual park information page and I removed the {{#each}} from the page.  for some reason the mongoose findById() with hbs was still looping through every item and the very first one was given the ID that was passed in.  Im sure there is a better way to do this so that I don't have to always create a separate page.  I'll update if I find any more information.